# Set TextView text with a for loop so multiple lines show

Tags: java, android, textview, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

So I have a for loop that I want to output a new line in a textview every single time it goes through. However, I am not sure if that is possible. I have TableLayout in there but it put the items vertically instead of horizontally. I thought about ListView but not sure how to set the text of it.

Here is my code

```
    import android.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;


/**
 * Created by James Singleton on 8/13/2016.
 */

public class WeeklyDrives extends Fragment implements APIRequestsUtil.APIRequestResponseListener
{
    View myView;
    Map<String, Route> drives;
    private TextView driveNumber;
    private TextView driveDistance;
    private TextView driveTime;
    private TextView driveNumList;
    private TextView driveDistList;
    private TextView driveTimeList;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weekly_drives, container, false);
        APIRequestsUtil.setOnNetWorkListener(this);

        return myView;
    }


    private void populateView() {
        this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                drives = APIRequestsUtil.getRoutes();

                driveNumber = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.Drive_Number);
                driveDistance = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.Drive_Distance);
                driveTime = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.Drive_Time);

                driveNumber.setText("Drive Num.");
                driveDistance.setText("Distance");
                driveTime.setText("Time");
                int driveNum = 0;
                for (Map.Entry drive : drives.entrySet()) {
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
                    Route route = (Route) drive.getValue();
                    tr.setId(driveNum++);
                    //tr.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    DateTime startTime = new DateTime(route.getStart_time());
                    DateTime endTime = new DateTime(route.getEnd_time());


                    driveNumList = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.Drive_Number_List);
                    driveDistList = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.Drive_Distance_List);
                    driveTimeList = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.Drive_Time_List);

                    driveNumList.setText(driveNumList.getText().toString() + String.valueOf(driveNum) + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    driveDistList.setText(driveDistList.getText().toString() + Float.parseFloat(route.getLen()) / 1000 + " km" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    driveTimeList.setText(driveTimeList.getText().toString() + ((endTime.getMillis() - startTime.getMillis())/ 1000)/60 + " min" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Request request, Throwable throwable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response response) {
        populateView();
    }
}
```

Here is my XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Header aligned to top -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FC9">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Drive_Number"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Drive_Distance"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Drive_Number"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Drive_Time"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Drive_Distance"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#000"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="#005"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:id="@+id/scrollableContents">

        <!--<TableLayout-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/fragment1_tlayout"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:stretchColumns="0,1">-->

        <!--</TableLayout>-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Drive_Number_List"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Drive_Distance_List"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Drive_Number_List"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#CCCCCC"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Drive_Time_List"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Drive_Distance_List"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#CCCCCC"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`drive.entrySet()` output

```
What is this:[2016-07-11--08-52-18=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@12a862, 2016-07-11--09-37-46=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@50bbdf3, 2016-07-11--18-54-22=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@6d21ab0, 2016-07-12--09-15-59=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@fb72d29, 2016-07-12--09-29-29=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@776e8ae, 2016-07-12--09-33-03=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@d1a464f, 2016-07-12--09-38-56=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@5b631dc, 2016-07-12--09-41-08=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@dec72e5, 2016-07-12--09-42-39=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@acce1ba, 2016-07-12--09-44-33=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@5def86b, 2016-07-12--09-49-31=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@d628fc8, 2016-07-12--09-54-06=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@7765861, 2016-07-12--19-04-34=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@8575f86, 2016-07-12--19-39-20=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@3f2b047, 2016-07-12--19-40-27=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@df4e074, 2016-07-12--19-41-28=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@b5f199d, 2016-07-13--08-45-17=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@db9ee12, 2016-07-13--09-01-32=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@2a009e3, 2016-07-13--15-02-04=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@9b98fe0, 2016-07-14--08-46-22=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@518b299, 2016-07-14--19-22-46=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@d44d95e, 2016-07-14--19-34-02=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@d3f613f, 2016-07-14--20-16-47=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@957ca0c, 2016-07-15--08-36-28=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@b38df55, 2016-07-15--09-52-32=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@c012d6a, 2016-07-15--12-09-57=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@252d25b, 2016-07-15--12-15-07=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@6bd7af8, 2016-07-15--15-36-10=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route@df51bd1,
```

Comment: If you have a lot of data to display, it's best to use a ListView.

Comment: I do have a lot of data to display, roughly 430 drives. But couldn't figure out a way to set the text of it and get it how I wanted.

Comment: @mikeyaworski how would I go about implementing a listview? And what is the pro and cons?

Comment: I'm writing up a solution for you. Pros: better organization and it only renders views that the user is currently looking at. It does view recycling so that it is efficient at displaying infinitely long lists. Cons: it's a little harder to implement.

Comment: Ooo that would probably be better as some people that will be using this will have close to 1,000 drives! :O

Comment: What exactly does `drives.entrySet()` return? Is it a `List` of `Map.Entry`s? Or a regular array of `Map.Entry`s? Or something else?

Comment: Give me one second, the person I am collaborating with wrote this bit, I am in charge of UI stuff for this part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122476/discussion-between-james-robert-singleton-and-mike-yaworski).

Comment: I have updated my original question with a sample output. Don't mind the "What is this:" just my way of tracking in the logs :)

Comment: I posted my answer. You may have issues with it. Let me know what issues you have, or if it works great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` to the `TextView` in the XML.

And add data into TextView like this:

```
driveNumList.setText(driveNumList.getText().toString() + String.valueOf(driveNum) + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

And so on.

**Edit:** you can use `"\n"` instead of `System.getProperty("line.separator")` for adding the new line character.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! Now I just have to figure out how to get it to center under the headers and I am set for this portion.

Comment: I tried to edit your .toString to .toString() to be technically correct but it isn't longer than 6 characters haha

Comment: Thankyou. There is always a syntax error in my code no matter how much i try :( :P

Comment: Haha no worries! Thank you for showing me this. I was trying the textMultiLine earlier but it wasn't working how it is now.

Comment: Possibly because of conflict between attributes. It is better to clear your mind before moving on like jvm garbage collector does. ;D

Comment: Yea, I have been working on this for roughly 5 hours now.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a ListView for this type of thing so that it is automatically scrollable, uses View recycling to maintain efficiency, cleans up your code and organizes it into digestible segments.

To use a ListView, you first need to add it to your main XML file. So that would become the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Header aligned to top -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FC9">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Drive_Number"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Drive_Distance"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Drive_Number"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Drive_Time"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Drive_Distance"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#000"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="#005"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:id="@+id/scrollableContents">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Following that, you need to create your ListView adapter class. It is what handles what each *individual* list item's data is (the thing inside your for-loop).

Here is one that you might use, although you may have to make your own tweaks and import more of your own classes, **add your package name to the top**, etc.

So create a new Java class called `DriveListAdapter.java` and place the following code into it:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DriveListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Map.Entry> {

    private final Activity context;
    // you may need to change List to something else (whatever is returned from drives.entrySet())
    private final List<Map.Entry> drives;

    // may also need to change List here (above comment)
    public DriveListAdapter(Activity context, List<Map.Entry> drives) {
        super(context, R.layout.drive_list_item, drives);
        this.context = context;
        this.drives = drives;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drive_list_item, null, true);

        Map.Entry drive = this.drives.get(position);

        // position is the index of the drives.entrySet() array
        int driveNum = position + 1;

        // need to import your Route class
        Route route = (Route) drive.getValue();

        // need to import your DateTime class
        DateTime startTime = new DateTime(route.getStart_time());
        DateTime endTime = new DateTime(route.getEnd_time());

        TextView driveNumList = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Drive_Number_List);
        TextView driveDistList = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Drive_Distance_List);
        TextView driveTimeList = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Drive_Time_List);

        driveNumList.setText(String.valueOf(driveNum));
        driveDistList.setText(Double.parseDouble(route.getLen()) / 1000 + " km");
        driveTimeList.setText((endTime.getMillis() - startTime.getMillis())/ 1000 + " s");

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Then, create a new layout file, which will be what the individual list item looks like. This layout is rendered for each and every drive in the list. You can adjust this layout file so that everything is aligned properly. I gave an example of how to do that (create a layout file called `drive_list_item.xml`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/Drive_Number_List"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/Drive_Distance_List"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/Drive_Time_List"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And lastly, you just need to populate that ListView you created in the first step with this new adapter class.

So use the following method (populates the ListView instead of using the for loop):

```
private void populateView() {
    this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            drives = APIRequestsUtil.getRoutes();

            driveNumber = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.Drive_Number);
            driveDistance = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.Drive_Distance);
            driveTime = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.Drive_Time);

            driveNumber.setText("Drive Number");
            driveDistance.setText("Drive Distance");
            driveTime.setText("Drive Time");

            // edit: you need to generate your List data from the entrySet
            // the ArrayAdapter cannot take a Set argument - needs to be a List
            List<Map.Entry> list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry>();
            for (Map.Entry drive : drives.entrySet()) {
                list.add(drive);
            }

            // populate the ListView
            // may need to change "getActivity()" to something else
            // this constructor needs the "this" context of the activity 
            DriveListAdapter drivesListAdapter = new DriveListAdapter(getActivity(), list);
            ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setAdapter(drivesListAdapter);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So how does this tie into my WeeklyDrives.java? Because that is the fragment that everything will be displayed on.

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton I'm not sure. Try it out and see what happens.

Comment: Most of the populateView() is red. This was meant to go into the DriveListAdapter.java right? Also, why not put that stuff into the weeklydrives.java instead of making a new class?

Comment: Also, what is the layout supposed to be in here `super(context, R.layout.drive_list_item, drives);`

Comment: Also, am I supposed to be calling DriveListAdapter somewhere because it says it is never used?

Comment: Why is populateView mostly red? I only added 3 lines. Are my three lines red? And I'm not sure what WeeklyDrives.java is, so I can't say. The list adapter normally goes into it's own class, though. And the layout file for the individual items should be called `drive_list_item`. I forgot to put that in my post. Or you can change `R.layout.drive_list_item` to whatever you named the XML file instead.

Comment: Is your populateView replacing mine? If so then there might be an issue. It looks like the beginning of my code either got edited out or I forgot to put it. Either way I have added everything. So the populateView I originally had is in my WeeklyDrives.java which is my fragment that I call to populate my Navigation Drawer Menu item called Weekly Drives.

Comment: Okay, well just replace your for-loop in populateView with my three lines starting at `DriveListAdapter`... and see how that works. You don't need to copy my populateView. Just the three lines I wrote.

Comment: Also, you may need to replace `(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView)` with `(ListView)myView.findViewById(R.id.listView)`

Comment: So I replaced my populateView with yours, and now the only thing that is red is `DriveListAdapter drivesListAdapter = new DriveListAdapter(getActivity(), drives.entrySet());`

It says:

DriveListAdapter
(Activity,
java.util.List<java.util.Map.Entry>)
in DriveListAdapter cannot be applied
to
(Activity,
java.util.Set<java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.String,com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.com.examples.jamessingleton.chffrapi.data.Route>>)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122489/discussion-between-james-robert-singleton-and-mike-yaworski).

Comment: And if I do the suggested thing from Android Studio "Change 2nd parameter of method 'DriveListAdapter' from 'List<Entry>' to 'Set<Entry<String, Route>>'."  It then underlines the public DriveListAdapter (Activity context, List<Map.Entry> drives)

Comment: Sorry for not responding quickly. Let me try getting this to work in my own environment. Then I'll update my answer.

Comment: No worries, it's 2 in the morning where I'm at. So I'm off to bed, thank you for your help so far on this. If you reply later on I'll let you know sometime in the next 9-10 hrs if it works haha

Comment: Okay. I added a few extra lines above the previous three lines I added. Put those into your method and see if it works.

Comment: So the `List<Map.Entry> list = new ArrayList<String>();` is underlined saying "Incompatible types. Required:List<java.util.Map.Entry> Found:ArrayList<java.lang.String>" Furthermore, I asked the person I am working on this with what `drives.entrySet()` returns and he said the following "Drives entryset () returns the entries in the map. Keys and values."

Comment: This is the error `Error:(78, 105) error: incompatible types: Set<Entry<String,Route>> cannot be converted to List<Entry>`

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton I changed the code again. `List<Map.Entry> list = new ArrayList<String>();` was a typo. It should have been `List<Map.Entry> list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry>();`. If there are still issues, then try adding `<String, Route>` beside `Entry`. If there are still issues, I can't really help because I just don't know enough about the code. You can try fiddling, or getting the other guy to fiddle with making the types compatible.

Comment: So I don't think I saw the `(getActivity(), this)` change you made.

Comment: Weird, it works but the drive distance is under the drive number and the drive number under the drive distance haha

Comment: Everything looks correct, so not sure why it would be putting them in the wrong order.

Comment: Figured it out :)

Comment: The only thing is the alignment is slightly off, pushing things off the screen and if I go to landscape mode it gets rid of everything and if I go back to portrait it shows blank. But that is an entirely different issue.

Comment: Question, would I be able to use this to populate a spinner as well? In one of my menu items I want to populate a spinner (dropdown menu) with the drive numbers for a user to select. I was thinking that I could follow the same logic here maybe?

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton I'm not sure how populating a spinner would work. I suggest Googling that and looking at some tutorials. I just don't know enough about spinner to be able to help. Glad your problem was fixed, though :) It'll be much easier for you to maintain with this coding style. It's easy to edit the file for the individual TextView layouts and make sure they're aligned.

Comment: not sure how to do this as I have tried a couple things and can't get it to work. But the drive number isn't centered under the header and the drive time is pushed off the edge as to where you can only see mi instead of min. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you use LinearLayout instead of TableLayoyt

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llMainLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

try this code

```
LinearLayout llMain=(LinearLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.llMainLayout);
for (Map.Entry drive : drives.entrySet()) {
            LinearLayout tr = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                  tr.setOrientation(1); // horizontal
            Route route = (Route) drive.getValue();
            tr.setId(driveNum++);
            // set params 
            DateTime startTime = new DateTime(route.getStart_time());
            DateTime endTime = new DateTime(route.getEnd_time());

            TextView driveNumList = new TextView(); 
            TextView driveDistList = new TextView(); 
            TextView driveTimeList = new TextView(); 

            driveNumList.setText(String.valueOf(driveNum));
            driveDistList.setText(Double.parseDouble(route.getLen()) / 1000 + " km");
            driveTimeList.setText((endTime.getMillis() - startTime.getMillis())/ 1000 + " s");
            tr.addView(driveNumList);
            tr.addView(driveDistList);
            tr.addView(driveTimeList);

          llMain.addView(tr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not using a tablelayout. That was originally put in there as a place holder just to get things shown. However, the tablelayout is commented out in the above code and switched to a linearlayout already. I just have a bunch of textviews haha

Comment: I have not as I accepted an answer already. If you want to know if it works, I can try it tomorrow morning and let you know though :)